# Re-render component with useEffect when something changes in a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rerender, use-effect

I have an application that lets a user to add tasks in a list. The tasks are fetched from the API and are displayed with the "List" component. When a user adds a new task from the "AddButton" component the task is stored in the database.
I want the to re-render the  "List" component when the handleSubmit function happens on the "AddButton" component and adds the task to the database. The "addTask" and "getTasks" are fetching data from the API. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

List component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import { getTasks } from './services/getTasks';
import AddButton from './AddButton';
import './App.css';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    height: '100%',
    fontSize: '16px',
  },
  listItemLinkRoot: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(3),
    width: '100%',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#212121',
      color: 'white',
    },
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },

  buttonContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },

  list: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    overflow: 'auto',
  },

  listItemText: {
    marginBottom: 8,
    // fontSize: 20,
  },
}));

function ListItemLink(props) {
  return <ListItem button component="a" {...props} />;
}

export default function TaskList() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await getTasks();
      setTasks(result);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <List classes={{ root: classes.list }}>
        {tasks.map(task => (
          <ListItemLink
            divider
            key={task.id}
            classes={{ root: classes.listItemLinkRoot }}
            href="simple-list"
          >
            <ListItemText
              classes={{ root: classes.listItemText }}
              primary={task.description}
            />
            <Moment
              classes={{ root: classes.listItemDate }}
              format="DD/MM/YYYY"
            >
              {task.createdAt}
            </Moment>
          </ListItemLink>
        ))}
      </List>
      <div className={classes.buttonContainer}>
        <AddButton classes={{ root: classes.add }} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

AddButton component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { addTask } from './services/postTask';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  cont: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingBottom: '24px',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0',
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    felxGrow: 1,
  },
  fab: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    width: '100%',
  },

  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
    marginTop: 0,
    marginBottom: 0,
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

export default function AddButton() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [task, setTask] = useState({
    description: '',
    completed: false,
  });

  const handleChange = ev => {
    setTask({ ...task, [ev.target.id]: ev.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    addTask(task);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.cont}>
      <TextField
        onChange={handleChange}
        id="description"
        label="Add a task"
        rowsMax="4"
        className={classes.textField}
        margin="normal"
      />
      <Fab
        onClick={handleSubmit}
        variant="extended"
        size="small"
        color="primary"
        aria-label="add"
        className={classes.fab}
      >
        <AddIcon />
        Add
      </Fab>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I would use name instead of id for inputs since id has to be unique for the entire document and no component can or should guarantee that a certain id is already taken by another component.

Comment: If List manages tasks why not just pass addTask to the button from the list and have it set the state when the task is added?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your time. Can you please clarify your second comment?

Comment: Concerning your first comment, do you mean to use name instead of id in the handleChange function?
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In your list component you can have your handleSubmit function and pass it down to your child AddButton component:

```
<AddButton classes={{ root: classes.add }} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
If i have the handleSubmit function in the List component how is it possible to now which task to add to the list since the handleChange function is in a different component?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of is to move the `fetchData` function outside of your `useEffect` hook and pass it to the Button as a prop:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
     const result = await getTasks();
     setTasks(result);
 };

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

...

<AddButton classes={{ root: classes.add }} refetch={fetchData}/>
```

Then in AddButton (assuming `addTask()` is async).

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    addTask(task)
      .then(res => props.refetch())
  };
```

Though it may make more sense to handle all of the state functionality in the parent component.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your response. I also thought of that but i would like to handle the state in the List component as you mention. I think i becomes more complicated to handle it in the button component. 
Thanks anyway though for your time.